# javascript - create an event on dynamic graph

Tags: javascript, html, graph

I have created a dynamic Bar graph using visualize function and visualize.css the value for graphs is given through HTML table now I want to perform an event on that graph.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom event:

```
(function() {

    /**
     * Small event class, can be instanciated as an object or using .call used to decorate other
     * Objects with events funcitonality. 
     */
    MyEvent.Event = function() {

        this.events = {};

        this.bind = function(eventName, func) {

            if (!this.events[eventName]) {
                this.events[eventName] = [];
            }

            this.events[eventName].push(func);
        };

        this.trigger = function(eventName, args, scope) {

            if (this.events[eventName]) {

                var len = this.events[eventName].length,
                    funcArgs = (jQuery.isArray(args)) ? args : [args];

                // This will go from back to front through the array not sure if this really matters?
                while (len--) {         
                    this.events[eventName][len].apply(scope || window, funcArgs);
                }
            }
        }

        this.removeAllEvents = function() {
            this.events = {};
        }
    };

    // Page level events class
    MyEvent.pageEvents = new MyEvent.Event();

})();
```

trigger it:

```
MyEvent.pageEvents.trigger("Method-name", "data"));
```

and Finally listen it:

```
MyEvent.pageEvents.bind("Method-name", function(Data) {
    //Code goes here
});
```

**USING JQUERY?**

Take a look at [trigger and bind](http://jamiethompson.co.uk/web/2008/06/17/publish-subscribe-with-jquery/).